# Is it possible to define a cubic function as a set of points equidistant to two objects?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, cubics

Im currently wondering whether one can define a cubic function in a similar way to a parabola, a parabola being a set of points equidistant to a point and a line. Maybe a cubic function would be equidistant to a line and a parabola?

Comment: Not an answer, a real comment: I hope you’re aware that although all quadratic functions have graphs of the same shape (parabola), there are different shapes for cubic functions, unless you are thinking of the one cubic function $y=x^3$. I do think it would be fun to see what your suggestion looks like when the calculation is done.

Comment: +1 to Lubin's comment re, **manually** graphing this would be a nightmare.  Thankfully, there is a wide variety of **free graphing software** that you can download.  One approach that allows pdf creation is latex, as discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX.  Latex users will often gravitate towards PSTricks, PGF-Tikz, or Asymptote as a "Latex plugins".

Comment: To expand-upon @Lubin's comment: See Wikipedia's ["Cubic plane curve" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve) for a sense of the variety of shapes a cubic curve can take. The entry links to ["A Gallery of Cubic Plane Curves" (via milefoot.com)](http://www.milefoot.com/math/planecurves/cubics.htm) that shows a few dozen of those shapes, noting some characteristics of each. [This History of Science and Mathematics SE question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5224) discusses the classification of cubics into as many as 219(!) types.

Comment: How is defined the distance point-parabola?

Comment: Superb question, @Raffaele . Presumably, you find the point on the parabola where the normal (line perpendicular to the tangent) contains your starting point. Then calculate the distance from the point to that point on the parabola. It’s easy-enough calculus, but I think it might be a pain to write down the formula involving the given point’s coordinates. A nice diversion for a cold late-autumn afternoon (which is what I’m facing here in Minnesota). I’m sorry my colleague Tom Banchoff is not listening in.